# Trouble configuring presto connection post upgrade

Tags: sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I'm trying to test an upgrade from 0.36 to 1.2.0, its mostly OK but I can't get the presto connection to work, its prestosql 336 which later became trino, the connection in 336 was configured as presto, I've tried changing the uri to be trino: with no affect

URI is of the form `presto://<username>:<password>@<server fqdn>:4039`

with the following in extra

```
{
    "metadata_params": {},
    "engine_params": {"connect_args": { "protocol": "https", "source": "superset", "requests_kwargs": {"verify": "/home/ec2-user/bundle_truststore.pem"}}},
    "metadata_cache_timeout": {},
    "schemas_allowed_for_csv_upload": []
}
```

This all gives me the following error which isnt very helpful `ERROR: (builtins.NoneType) None`

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/dbapi)

All of the above works on superset 0.36

Any suggestions where I can at least look for a more useful error or anything I can try?

[image: Error message]

[image: database config]

Answer (score 0):

To use trino (trino://) for latest version of superset, you need sqlalchemy-trino